# read complex json schema with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a json document into dataframe. But, its in a complex format. 
I was able to use explode function to get the values.

```
root
 |-- Name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Adap: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Vid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Information: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Caption: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- No: string (nullable = true)
 |-- License: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Out: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- In: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- INS: string (nullable = true)
```

Although the Json is large and i don't want to write everything manually. 
The way i did was for all values:

```
mdmDF.withColumn("Name", explode("Name")).select(col("Name")["Adap"].alias("Name.Adap")))
```

Secondly i tried: Although it only give me one dataframe per column.!

Name= mdmDF.selectExpr("explode(Name) AS Name").selectExpr("Name.*")

```
+------------------+----------+
|    Name          |      Adap|      
+------------------+----------+
|NVIDIA            |         0|
+------------------+----------+
```

What i want:

```
+------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|    adap          |      vid |  Caption |     no   |     Out  |    In    |
+------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|NVIDIA            |         0|      test|      1   |     etx  |    val   |
+------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data in json and what you expect at the end ?

Comment: @Steven: I edited the question with the expectations. The License values are more than hundred structs. and It wont be good to write manually the names.

Comment: Can you please specify where are you reading the json from? If it is from a SQL table, a text file...

Comment: @GasparAvitFerrero Hi, im reading it from a json document.

Comment: I'd say you should apply `flatMap` function which returns you rdd, but then you would have to apply a new schema to make it DataFrame

Comment: You should provide more information about what you have tried, including code for loading the data.